# Snort signatures not working

Tags: snort, tcp

I am using `snort` to detect signature for IDS but some rule not detected by snort which is highlighted below. Kindly, sort this out, I'm stuck here.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted the code in the question instead of using a screenshot. You also do not include enough information for us to answer you.